# How do I use color.branch.* values in Git's for-each-ref?

Tags: git

The Git docs for [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref/2.8.3) have an entry for `color` fields in the `--format` option, which says:

> Change output color. Followed by `:<colorname>`, where names are described in `color.branch.*`

The [`config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.8.3) docs say:

> `color.branch.<slot>`
>
> ... `<slot>` is one of `current` (the current branch), `local` (a local branch), `remote` (a remote-tracking branch in `refs/remotes/`), `upstream` (upstream tracking branch), `plain` (other refs).

But doing:

```
 git for-each-ref --format="%(color:current)%(refname:short)%(color:reset)" refs/heads
```

...gives me this error:

```
error: invalid color value: current
fatal: unrecognized color: %(color:current)
```

What's the required syntax here? (I'm using Git 2.8.3 on Windows, but get the same error on Git 2.7.4 under Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 2):

The actual code to handle colors is in [`color.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c), which allows:

- the special words [`reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L210) and [`normal`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L74-L75);
- the words [`black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`,
  `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan`, and `white`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L67-L68);
- a numeric value in [eight bit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L99-L100) or [24 bit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L80-L81) format;
- modifiers [`bold`, `dim`, `italic`, `ul`, `blink`, `reverse`, and `strike`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L74-L75), optionally prefixed with [`no` or `no-`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.c#L146-L147);

which can be done up to twice, to specify both foreground and background color.  (This is also documented [near the top of the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_values).)

The documentation does seem to say that one might use `current`, `local`, etc.; but [in fact,](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ref-filter.c#L203) [one cannot](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ref-filter.c#L52-L57); the only allowed modifiers to `%(refname)` itself, which might be the other place to squeeze this in, are [`:short` and `:strip=<n>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ref-filter.c#L1035-L1047).  Perhaps the documentation is ahead of the code (though note that these direct-to-github links, which will probably become invalid over time since they're by line number, are to an even newer Git).

Comment: I linked to documentation for the version of Git that I'm using, but I didn't see any changes with the current version.

Comment: Perhaps a shorter answer might be better: "the documentation is wrong"? :-)